# Assignment and retrieval along with Post increment in single line in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

This is the code which I ran.

```
int minimumCardPickup(vector<int>& cards) {
        int N = cards.size();
        int l = 0, r = 0, res = INT_MAX;
        unordered_map<int, int> pos;
        
        while (r < N) {
            if (pos.find(cards[r]) != pos.end()) {
                l = pos[cards[r]];
                res = min(res, r - l + 1);
            }
            pos[cards[r]] = r++; //Here
        }
        
        return res == INT_MAX ? -1 : res;
    }
```

let's take an example:
cards = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
The line with the comment should update the map to the following after 3 iterations:

```
pos = {[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2]}
```

But instead it updates the map like this:

```
pos = {[2, 0], [3, 1]}
```

It should have done something like this: get value of `cards[r]` and then assign `pos[cards[r]]` with the value of `r` and then do `r++` for next iteration but instead, it did `r++` then get value of `cards[r]` and then assign `pos[cards[r]]` with value of `r` before increment.

If I do this, it works fine.

```
pos[cards[r]] = r;
r++;
```

Can someone explain why it works like that?

Comment: Don't play games like that, it's just not worth it.  Do it the straightforward way and let the compiler optimise your code - that's what it's good at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly identified, the problem is here:

```
pos[cards[r]] = r++; //Here
```

In earlier standards:

If you post-increment or post-decrement a variable, you should not read the value of it again before a sequence point (in this case, `;`). This is because post-increment might occur any time during the statement (as long as the expression evaluates to the old value).

From C++17, for any operation `l = r`, the evaluation of `r` is sequenced-before the evaluation of `l` (including side effects), so it’s a valid expression, but still not what’s expected in the code. Either do the post-increment on the left-hand side of the `=` (thereby restricting to c++17 and newer), or simply do the increment as a distinct statement (as you correctly specified).

Comment: C++ had no sequence points since C++11. OP's code is legal starting from C++17.

Comment: Post was not tagged with specific standard version. In later standards, it’s sequenced-before and sequenced-after. Particularly in C++17, the above code also won’t work as the user expected: in any assignment, `l = r`, evaluation of `r` is sequenced-before evaluation of `l`. So it’s valid, but still an error in this case. (Updating answer with this).